# How to get repetitive records in aggregate field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have prepared a query:

```sql
SELECT
building_custom."Location Code",
building_custom."RUD Site Name",
string_agg(concat_ws('-',subnet.range_begin,subnet.range_end),',')
FROM building
INNER JOIN building_custom ON building.building_pk=building_custom.building_fk
INNER JOIN device ON building.building_pk=device.building_fk
INNER JOIN ipaddress ON device.device_pk=ipaddress.device_fk
INNER JOIN subnet ON ipaddress.subnet_fk=subnet.subnet_pk
GROUP BY
building_custom."Location Code",
building_custom."RUD Site Name"
```

What I'm getting as result is:

```
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;141.167.161.17-141.167.161.18,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,0.0.0.1-255.255.255.254,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,141.167.161.21-141.167.161.22,0.0.0.1-255.255.255.254,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30
```

The last field (subnet range) contains duplicated values.

The goal is to have result as this below:

```
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;0.0.0.1-255.255.255.254,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,141.167.161.17-141.167.161.18,141.167.161.21-141.167.161.22,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30
```

At first I was trying to add

```sql
DISTINCT ON (view_subnet_v1.range_begin)
```

But then I needed to add this in GROUP BY and the results were even worse:

```
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;0.0.0.1-255.255.255.254,0.0.0.1-255.255.255.254
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30,10.120.10.1-10.120.10.30
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254,10.120.11.1-10.120.11.254
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254,10.120.16.1-10.120.16.254
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;141.167.161.17-141.167.161.18
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;141.167.161.21-141.167.161.22
DBA;BUENOS AIRES-ARENALES;141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30,141.167.161.25-141.167.161.30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using distinct with an inner query:

```
 SELECT
    "Location Code",
    "RUD Site Name" ,
    string_agg(concat_ws('-',range_begin,range_end),',') from 
    (SELECT distinct 
    building_custom."Location Code",
    building_custom."RUD Site Name",
    subnet.range_begin
    ,subnet.range_end
    FROM building
    INNER JOIN building_custom ON building.building_pk=building_custom.building_fk
    INNER JOIN device ON building.building_pk=device.building_fk
    INNER JOIN ipaddress ON device.device_pk=ipaddress.device_fk
    INNER JOIN subnet ON ipaddress.subnet_fk=subnet.subnet_pk
) inner_q
    GROUP BY
    "Location Code",
    "RUD Site Name"
```

In addition, if you would like to have only the widest subnet you might use `min` , `max` and `group by` rather than `distinct` in your inner query